# C++ function to split string by delimiter and return the last

Tags: c++, string, split

Like we have string = "Cow eat Grass/Cat eat mouse/Dog eat meat/Fish eat worm/Snake eat mouse"
I try to make function like:

```
std::string getTheLastAnimalText(const std::string& source)

{

// .... Can you help here :) 

return "Snake eat mouse";
```

I try to make this function but i can't ;(

Comment: You can search the string backwards for your delimiter character using `rbegin` and `rend` in combination with `std::find()`.

Comment: Read about [`std::basic_string::rfind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind). In particular, the variation marked "(4)".

Comment: Reopened. The question is about searching for a **single character** delimiter. The claimed duplicate is about searching for a **string** delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::basic_string::find_last_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) and [std::basic_string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), like following.

Also if you need supporting several delimiters, e.g. also comma, then replace in my code `"/"` with `"/,"`.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/ex9TT38no)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string getTheLastAnimalText(std::string const & source) {
    return source.substr(source.find_last_of("/") + 1);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << getTheLastAnimalText("Cow eat Grass/Cat eat mouse/Dog eat meat/Fish eat worm/Snake eat mouse");
}
```

Output:

```
Snake eat mouse
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::string::find_last_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) as shown below:

```
const std::string input = "Cow eat Grass/Cat eat mouse/Dog eat meat/Fish eat worm/Snake eat mouse";
auto const pos = input.find_last_of('/');
const auto last = input.substr(pos + 1);
std::cout << last<< std::endl;             //prints Snake eat mouse
```